# Can libnet be used to inject tcp packets/packet mangling?

Tags: c++, c, libnet

I just took a glance at the introduction of [libnet](http://libnet.sourceforge.net/),

seems it mentioned support for **udp**,**ip**,but not **tcp**?

Does it support **tcp** at all?

Answer (score 0):

Looking [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libnet), there seems to be a function related to tcp, so I guess yes, you can inject tcp segments with libnet.

```
int libnet_build_tcp(u_short sport, u_short dport, u_long seq,
            u_long ack, u_char control, u_short win, u_short urg,
            const u_char *payload, int payload_s, u_char *buf);
```

> libnet_build_tcp() builds a TCP
>   (Transmission Control Protocol)
>   packet. Supplied is the source port,
>   destination port, the sequence and
>   acknowledgement numbers, the control
>   bits (which can be logically OR'd
>   together to set multiple flags -- see
>   the example below), the advertised
>   window size, the urgent pointer, a
>   pointer to an optional data payload,
>   the payload size, and lastly, the
>   pointer to a pre-allocated block of
>   memory for the packet. To just build a
>   TCP header with no data payload, only
>   TCP_H bytes need be allocated.